# use filter of Lodash/Javascript to get the filtered data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have two array of objects.

```
const firstObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Peter" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John" },
  { Id: "12", Name: "jessy" },
];

const secondObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Roa", original: { Id: "1" } },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John2", original: { Id: "2" } },
  { Id: "5", Name: "Rachel", original: { Id: "3" } },
];
```

Here, I am trying to filter data on the basis of Id and return the filtered `firstObj`

So, here firstObj has an entry  `{ Id: "12", Name: "jessy" }` this object whose Id does not match with the `secondObj.original.Id` so, `firstObj` will have the given result.

what I tried was

```
firstObj.filter(
  firstObj,
  secondObj.map((second) => {
    return firstObj.Id === second.original.Id;
  }),
);
```

But this does not work. Can any one help me out here , using Lodash or Js filter.

```
output would be -> [{"Id": "3", "Name": "jessy"}]
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of what the output should be given those inputs?

Comment: This is not how [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works

Comment: @cbr I have updated the question please check

Comment: And why is the expected output as it is? Why `"jessy"` and not a different object?

Comment: @Andreas my bad actually,  I have just updated the question please check

Comment: The expected output doesn't match any rules I can work out. You have entries that should be in the result (as far as I can tell) that aren't, and I can't begin to understand how `jessy` (with `Id: 12`) matches given it has a different `original.Id` in the second array...?

Comment: No , I mean, what I am trying is , if firstObj has an Id which matches with the second obj original Id then I am removing that object from firstObject

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for being a messy, but I have just updated the question and also added the comment please do check

Comment: But again, why does the object in the result have `Id: 3` when the object in the original first array has `Id: 12`? A *filtering* operation doesn't change the items passing through, it just *filters* them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
const firstObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Peter" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John" },
  { Id: "12", Name: "jessy" },
];

const secondObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Roa", original: { Id: "1" } },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John2", original: { Id: "2" } },
  { Id: "1", Name: "Rachel", original: { Id: "3" } },
];


const result = lodash.filter(firstObj, (firstItem) => {
  return !lodash.some(secondObj, (secondItem) => {
    return firstItem.Id === secondItem.original.Id;
  });
});
```

Live: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-addy5t?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

why use loadash for this. you can use native filter and find functions to achieve this

```
const filter = firstObj.filter(item => {
     return secondObj.find(itm => itm.original.id === item.id)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use native method of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to achieve the desired output.

Please check below working code snippet

**ES6**

```js
const firstObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Peter" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John" },
  { Id: "12", Name: "jessy" },
],
secondObj = [
  { Id: "1", Name: "Roa", original: { Id: "1" } },
  { Id: "2", Name: "John2", original: { Id: "2" } },
  { Id: "1", Name: "Rachel", original: { Id: "3" } },
];

let result = firstObj.filter(({Id})=> !secondObj.some(item => item.original.Id === Id));

console.log(result)
```